# Chrooted user logged out immediately after login

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, pam, chroot

I am trying to use chroot to setup a user who can login via ssh and limit access to the `/var/www` directory. The server is on AWS running Amazon Linux 64-bit, openssh installed. I used ssh-keygen to generate the keys.

Before I edit the `sshd_config` file, I am able to login with the username and private key, user starts in the `/home/my-username` directory, so the key is valid.

I modified the `sshd_config` file as follows:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match User my-username
ChrootDirectory /var/www
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
PermitTunnel no
X11Forwarding no
```

Then I restarted sshd.

The `ChrootDirectory /var/www` is owned by root:root with no groups having write privileges up to that point in the tree – default Apache install.

When I login with my-username and the key, the session immediately disconnects. I checked `/var/log/secure` and find this entry:

```
Nov  3 19:53:51 ip-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sshd[2945]: Accepted publickey for my-username from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 61821 ssh2
Nov  3 19:53:51 ip-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sshd[2945]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my-username by (uid=0)
Nov  3 19:53:51 ip-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sshd[2945]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user my-username
```

I have read numerous threads in many forums and see different solutions – some of which I’ve tried with no success. I’d like to keep this as simple as possible. The goal is to create a user account for a developer who only needs to upload files to the webserver using WinSCP, in the default case to `/var/www/html`.

I found this thread – [User gets instantly disconnected after connection sucessful on a chrooted SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742332/user-gets-instantly-disconnected-after-connection-sucessful-on-a-chrooted-ssh) - but not sure it relates directly to my issue.

I’m thinking this may have something to do with my PAM configuration. Again, this is pretty much a default install.

Thank you in advance for any direction you can provide.

Comment: Did you try connecting with sftp/scp?

Comment: Yes - I did.  Was going to update my question. WinSCP works fine and accomplishes what I set out to do.

Answer (score 0):

Chroot environments require the presence of all libraries and binaries necessary for normal operation. This includes all shared object files that the login shell is linked to. If you copy additional command binaries into this chroot, you will need their linker dependencies as well.

- Look for a guide on how to set up a chroot environment for ssh logins. Example that I found via Google: http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access)
- Consider whether you really want to create this chroot environment in /var/www. Do you *really* want `/var/www/dev`, `/var/www/lib`, etc.?

Comment: Andrew - thanks for the answer and the link.  I finally figured out this was what was booting me out with Putty.  WinSCP allows me to do what I want in this instance, load files to the web server public HTML folder - although there may be some other use cases where this will be helpful.